# Smart Beta Portfolio: How to generate the weights based on dollar volume traded for each date

Tags: python-3.x

```
def generate_dollar_volume_weights(close, volume):
     """
     Generate dollar volume weights.

     Parameters
     ----------
     close : DataFrame
           Close price for each ticker and date
     volume : str
            Volume for each ticker and date

     Returns
     -------
     dollar_volume_weights : DataFrame
                           The dollar volume weights for each ticker and date
      """
     assert close.index.equals(volume.index)
     assert close.columns.equals(volume.columns)

     #TODO: Implement function
     dollar_volume_weights=np.cumsum(close * volume) / np.cumsum(volume)

     return dollar_volume_weights
 project_tests.test_generate_dollar_volume_weights(generate_dollar_volume_weights)#testing the function
```

So my results are as below

```css
INPUT close:
                  XHNP        FCUB        ZYRP
2005-09-09 35.44110000 34.17990000 34.02230000
2005-09-10 92.11310000 91.05430000 90.95720000
2005-09-11 57.97080000 57.78140000 58.19820000
2005-09-12 34.17050000 92.45300000 58.51070000

INPUT volume:
                        XHNP              FCUB              ZYRP
2005-09-09  9836830.00000000 17807200.00000000  8829820.00000000
2005-09-10 82242700.00000000 68531500.00000000 48160100.00000000
2005-09-11 16234800.00000000 13052700.00000000  9512010.00000000
2005-09-12 10674200.00000000 56831300.00000000  9316010.00000000

OUTPUT dollar_volume_weights:
                  XHNP        FCUB        ZYRP
2005-09-09 35.44110000 34.17990000 34.02230000
2005-09-10 86.05884636 79.32405834 82.13590461
2005-09-11 81.84884187 76.49494177 78.71200871
2005-09-12 77.57172242 82.30022612 76.22980471

EXPECTED OUTPUT FOR dollar_volume_weights:
                 XHNP       FCUB       ZYRP
2005-09-09 0.27719777 0.48394253 0.23885970
2005-09-10 0.41632975 0.34293308 0.24073717
2005-09-11 0.41848548 0.33536102 0.24615350
2005-09-12 0.05917255 0.85239760 0.08842984
```

I'm a beginner here, I really can't understand what I'm missing here,  I think the expression for generating dollar volume weight should be some thing like `dollar_volume_weights=np.cumsum(close * volume) / np.cumsum(volume)` 
can someone tell me why my results are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do `close * volume` and divide by the sum (`np.sum(x, axis=1)`) of `volume * close` and specify the `axis=1`. Furthermore, you could use `div()` function for this division and specify `axis=0`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @joseph here. I assume you are talking about the Smart Beta project of Udacity. Their example in the prior cell is misleading and that confused the heck out of me. Anyway, the way I solved it is like the following:

```
def generate_dollar_volume_weights(close, volume):
    """
    Generate dollar volume weights.

    Parameters
    ----------
    close : DataFrame
        Close price for each ticker and date
    volume : str
        Volume for each ticker and date

    Returns
    -------
    dollar_volume_weights : DataFrame
        The dollar volume weights for each ticker and date
    """
    assert close.index.equals(volume.index)
    assert close.columns.equals(volume.columns)
    
    #TODO: Implement function
    print(close)
    print(volume)
    
    dollar_volume = close * volume
    print(dollar_volume)

    total_dollar_volume = dollar_volume.sum(axis=1)
    print(total_dollar_volume)
    
    dollar_volume_weights = dollar_volume.div(total_dollar_volume,axis=0)
    print(dollar_volume_weights)

    return dollar_volume_weights

project_tests.test_generate_dollar_volume_weights(generate_dollar_volume_weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more how you desire to calculate dollar_volume_weights from the input to get the expected result?

To be clear what your code is doing, the followings show the logic it computes the result,

```
2005-09-09 close * volume / volume  ...
2005-09-10 (close1*volume1) + (close2*volume2) / (volume1+volume2) ...
```

Comment: That's what it does, but I'm just wondering why my results are different from the expected! I'm supposed to test my function against the `test_generate_dollar_volume_weights` function. can't understand how they came about with their results! except that my formula for calculating `dollar_volume_weights` is wrong.

Comment: So you should ask them how their expected dollar_volume_weights came out as there is no easy way to guess the formula based on input and observed output unless this is machine learning.